# Microsoft Excel creating a tab delimeted file

Tags: ms-office, excel-2016

So, in my software program I need a comma separated file. Hence, I created one using Microsoft excel entering the data. But, my software program gave error saying its not a comma separated. Hence, I just copy pasted some cell in notepad and it came out to be Tab separated.

Right now :

```
Owner   Latitude    Longitude   LocationInfo
```

I want :

```
Owner,Latitude,Longitude,LocationInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Excel has its own special proprietary file format.
2. If you copy and past from an Excel sheet, what you get has no bearing on the format when you click save.

What you need to do is SaveAs and then in the popup where you can browse for a location and edit the file name, there is also a drop down (below the file name text box) where you can select various file extensions. When you pick one of those Excel will intelligently format your file for the chosen extension. Just find the one that is `.csv` (it may be called CSV).